# Spring, property value when having separators

Tags: java, spring, properties, inject

I am loading a properties file with

```
@PropertySource("classpath:propFile.properties")
```

In this property file I have the following entry:

```
list.of.stg=a,b,c
```

Further, I do:

```
@Value("${list.of.stg}")public void setSomeList(...)
{in the method, the parameter has only the value a!!!}
```

Can you please indicate me a way of reaching the complete values of the

```
list.of.stg
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
@Value("#{T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).commaDelimitedListToStringArray(environment['list.of.stg'])}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the the property value is passed in as a `String` you will have to use `String#split` but you can combine with [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html):

```
@Value("#{'${list.of.stg}'.split(',')}") 
public void setSomeList(List<String> list) {
   this.myList = list;
}
```

or simply on the class member variable

```
@Value("#{'${list.of.stg}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> myList;
```

---

As always when using the `@PropertySource` annotation, don't forget to create a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` `@Bean` to load the necessary property file(s).

Related: [@Value and ArrayList](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?129563-Value-and-ArrayList)

Comment: Thank you for the answer - valid indeed. However, the site allows me to 'tick' only one answer. I heve chosen the one given by Jose beucause you already have a looot of points:) sorry!:0